# How to detect trafic light color with histogram info using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I have some images from traffic lights:

[image: Red traffic light]
[image: Green traffic light]
[image: Yellow traffic light]

How can I know their color only using color histogram info using OpenCV?
I have the following:

```py
for img_file in glob.glob(f"{save_folder}/*"):
        img = cv2.imread(img_file)
        for i, col in enumerate(("b", "g", "r")):
            histr = cv2.calcHist([img], [i], None, [256], [0, 256])
            plt.plot(histr, color=col)
            plt.xlim([0, 256])
        plt.show()
```

The above code plots the color histogram for every image. I don't really know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Do you need to use the histogram? You could convert to HSV and look at the S channel. All shades of gray/black/white will have low saturation. So you could threshold on saturation to make a mask. Then get the average color of the pixels in the image corresponding to the white regions in the mask.

Comment: @fmw42 Yes the use of histogram is mandatory

Comment: @fmw42 Could you provide a detailed solution in a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My complete solution:** (thanks [fmw42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7355741/fmw42))

It's probably not optimal, but it's a good start point.

```py
# Dependencies
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure as exposure

def get_mid_arr(arr: np.ndarray, k: int) -> np.ndarray:
    mid_arr = arr.copy()
    upper = np.triu_indices(mid_arr.shape[0], k=k)
    mid_arr[upper] = 0
    lower = np.tril_indices(mid_arr.shape[0], k=-k)
    mid_arr[lower] = 0
    return mid_arr


def get_upper_arr(arr, k: int) -> np.ndarray:
    upper_arr = arr.copy()
    lower_triangle_indices = np.tril_indices(upper_arr.shape[0], k= k - 1)

    upper_arr[lower_triangle_indices] = 0

    return upper_arr


def get_lower_arr(arr, k: int) -> np.ndarray:
    lower_arr = arr.copy()
    upper_triangle_indices = np.triu_indices(lower_arr.shape[0], k = - k + 1)
    lower_arr[upper_triangle_indices] = 0
    return lower_arr


class TraficLightHistogramClassifier:
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        hist_cutting_treshold=55,  # optimal value found for my dataset
        probability_boundary=0.09,  # optimal value found for my dataset
    ) -> None:
        self.hist_cutting_treshold = hist_cutting_treshold
        self.probability_boundary = probability_boundary

    
    def predict(self, images_folder: str) -> list[str]:
        # Create empty list for holding predictions
        predictions = []
        # Search every image in the save folder
        for img_file in glob.glob(f"{images_folder}/*"):
            # Read image
            img = cv2.imread(img_file)
            # calculate 2D histograms for pairs of channels: GR
            hist = cv2.calcHist([img], [1, 2], None, [256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256])
            # hist is float and counts need to be scale to range 0 to 255
            scaled_hist = (
                exposure.rescale_intensity(hist, in_range=(0, 1), out_range=(0, 255))
                .clip(0, 255)
                .astype(np.float64)
            )

            # Split histogram into 3 regions
            (yellow_region, green_region, red_region) = (
                get_mid_arr(scaled_hist, self.hist_cutting_treshold),
                get_lower_arr(scaled_hist, self.hist_cutting_treshold),
                get_upper_arr(scaled_hist, self.hist_cutting_treshold),
            )

            # Count how many non zero values in each region
            (red_count, green_count, yellow_count) = (
                np.count_nonzero(red_region),
                np.count_nonzero(green_region),
                np.count_nonzero(yellow_region),
            )

            # Calculate total non-zero values
            total_count = red_count + green_count + yellow_count

            # Calculate red and green percentage
            red_percentage, green_percentage = (
                red_count / total_count,
                green_count / total_count,
            )

            # Logic for deciding color
            if green_percentage > self.probability_boundary:
                predict = "green"
            elif red_percentage > self.probability_boundary:
                predict = "red"
            else:
                predict = "yellow"

            # Append to predictions
            predictions.append(predict)
        return predictions


def main():

    y_true = [
        "green",
        "green",
        "green",
        "green",
        "red",
        "red",
        "yellow",
        "green",
        "green",
        "red",
        "red",
        "red",
        "red",
        "red",
        "green",
        "red",
        "red",
        "yellow",
        "green",
    ]

    # Create classifier
    clf = TraficLightHistogramClassifier()

    # "Predict" lights
    y_pred = clf.predict("Cropped Images")

    # Print true "labels"
    print(y_true)
    # Print predict "labels"
    print(y_pred)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to tell in Python/OpenCV using the G vs R 2D histogram. So if the 2D histogram has lots of white in the upper right, it is red, if along the lower left, it is green and if only along the diagonal, it is yellow.

So, make masks for the regions, mask the results and count the number of non-zero pixels using np.count_nonzero().

Input 1 (red)

[image]

Input 2 (green)

[image]

Input 3 (yellow)

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure as exposure
import os

filenames = ['traffic_light_red.jpg', 'traffic_light_green.jpg', 'traffic_light_yellow.jpg']

for filename in filenames:

    print(filename)

    # get name without suffix
    name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

    # read image
    img = cv2.imread(filename)

    # calculate 2D histograms for pairs of channels: GR
    histGR = cv2.calcHist([img], [1, 2], None, [256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256])

    # histogram is float and counts need to be scale to range 0 to 255
    histScaled = exposure.rescale_intensity(histGR, in_range=(0,1), out_range=(0,255)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

    # make masks
    ww = 256
    hh = 256
    ww13 = ww // 3
    ww23 = 2 * ww13
    hh13 = hh // 3
    hh23 = 2 * hh13
    black = np.zeros_like(histScaled, dtype=np.uint8)
    # specify points in OpenCV x,y format
    ptsUR = np.array( [[[ww13,0],[ww-1,hh23],[ww-1,0]]], dtype=np.int32 )
    redMask = black.copy()
    cv2.fillPoly(redMask, ptsUR, (255,255,255))
    ptsBL = np.array( [[[0,hh13],[ww23,hh-1],[0,hh-1]]], dtype=np.int32 )
    greenMask = black.copy()
    cv2.fillPoly(greenMask, ptsBL, (255,255,255))

    #Test histogram against masks
    region = cv2.bitwise_and(histScaled,histScaled,mask=redMask)
    redCount = np.count_nonzero(region)
    region = cv2.bitwise_and(histScaled,histScaled,mask=greenMask)
    greenCount = np.count_nonzero(region)
    print('redCount:',redCount)
    print('greenCount:',greenCount)

    # Find color
    threshCount = 100
    if redCount > greenCount and redCount > threshCount:
        color = "red"
    elif greenCount > redCount and greenCount > threshCount:
        color = "green"
    elif redCount < threshCount and greenCount < threshCount:
        color = "yellow"
    else:
        color = "other"
    print("color: ",color)  

    # save result
    cv2.imwrite(name + '_histogram.jpg', histScaled)
    cv2.imwrite('redMask.jpg', redMask)
    cv2.imwrite('greenMask.jpg', greenMask)

    # view results
    cv2.imshow("hist", histScaled)
    cv2.imshow("redMask", redMask)
    cv2.imshow("greenMask", greenMask)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    print('')
```

Red Mask:

[image]

Green Mask:

[image]

Red Histogram:

[image]

Green Histogram:

[image]

Yellow Histogram:

[image]

Results:

```
traffic_light_red.jpg
redCount: 2627
greenCount: 0
color:  red

traffic_light_green.jpg
redCount: 0
greenCount: 1138
color:  green

traffic_light_yellow.jpg
redCount: 0
greenCount: 0
color:  yellow
```

Comment: Great explanation of the 2D Hist! Imagine that I have a `hist_scaled` object (like your example), how can I programmatically check which distribution it follows (red, green, yellow)?

Comment: To take this further, you could make 3 masks for the 3 regions (upper right triangle, lower left triangle, and around the diagonal), mask the resulting histogram and count the number of non-zero pixels in each region using np.count_nonzero(). If lots in the upper right, it is red, if lots in the lower left it is green, if in neither, but only in the center diagonal region, it is yellow. (Untested)

Comment: I'll give it a test. Thanks

Comment: after some implementing 3 numpy masks, and fine-tuning their size, and the logic for deciding the color, I managed to get 100% accuracy on the full dataset. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post your full solution showing how you used the masks.

Comment: Best to post a new answer with your full solution.

Comment: I have modified my code to show how to use the masks